# Wait for page data in iron router - Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Is it possible to wait until the page data is loaded before page rendering? I always see the notFound template for a few milliseconds before the data is loaded.

Here is my code:

```
this.route('gamePage', {
        path: '/game/:slug/',
        onBeforeAction: filter,
        waitOn: function() { return [Meteor.subscribe('game', this.params.slug)]; },
        data: function() {
            var game =  Games.findOne({slug: this.params.slug});
            if (!game) {
                this.render("notFound");
            } else {
              return game;
            }
        }
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I solved it:

```
if (!game && this.ready()) {
       this.render("notFound");
 } else {
       return game;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `'loading'` hook to display a template of your choice while the subscriptions in `waitOn` are not yet ready.

Activate the hook:

```js
Router.onBeforeAction("loading");
```

And set a loading template:

```js
Router.configure({
  loadingTemplate: "loading"
});
```

```html
<template name="loading">
  loading... <!-- or display an animated spinner -->
</template>
```

You can also set the loading template on a per-route level.

```js
this.route("blah", {
  path: "/blah",
  loadingTemplate: "blahLoading"
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I actually already set a global loading template as you suggested with: `Router.configure({
  loadingTemplate: "loading"
});` in combination with `<template name="loading">
    <div id="spinner">
        {{> spinner}}
    </div>
</template>` but I don't get the desired results. I can only see the loading template on routes where I don't use `this.render("notFound");`. Any ideas?